# Is document view architecture unique to MFC

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

Is there any other class library like MFC which provides Document/View architecture or is it totally unique concept of MFC?

Comment: Why? What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

I realize that this is an old question, but for the benefit of those seeing this question via Google searches, the wxWidgets cross-platform GUI API contains a document-view framework as well.  I never used it before, so I cannot tell how it comparess with the MFC implementation.

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not, Apple used it for iPhone programming, at least until iOS 5 and if you take a look at the Stanford Universirty iOS Programming courses on iTunesU, you'll see that they'll teach it too. Moreover I've studied it in my OOP course here in Italy, so I can guess it's a worldwide accepted way to organize your code.

Answer (score 0):

Certainly the concept can be found in other languages/frameworks. But, if you compare MFC with WinForms and WPF, then yes, this technique is unique.